# What does the yellow color warning icon mean in Symfony2 web profiler?

Tags: symfony

It's a requests count did by my ORM (Doctrine), but why it's yellow?

### [image: screenshot]

Solution is a: http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Collector/db.html.twig#L6-L12

Yellow color mean only more than 50 requests and no more

Comment: Maybe you can click on it to have more informations. They are many possibility (too many request, ...).

Comment: Yes, i can do it, but no useful information inside it , only requests list. I don't think that 60 requests is so many..

Comment: Good to know for the alert at 50 request. Personally I try to never do more than 10 request.

Comment: Yes, but it's an index page with a lot of different entities, and with cache i have ~40 request )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My intuition is that "yellow" means something like :

> Notice: this a large amount of requests you should reduce for
>   performance reasons.

and "red" would mean :

> Warning: This is a huge amount of requests you should reduce for
>   performance reasons.

EDIT: Exact values that DoctrineBundle handles to choose color status for DB requests amount (vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Resources/views/Collector/db.html.twig) :

```
<span class="sf-toolbar-status{% if 50 < collector.querycount %} sf-toolbar-status-yellow{% endif %}">{{ collector.querycount }}</span>
```

- From 0 to 50 => green
- From 51 => yellow

No "red status" for DB requests amount

Comment: Red status also available, but as i remember only for an errors

Answer (score 1):

It's the number of request to the database (did by your orm). 
You can reduce this by using join and an Entity repository instead of using the default method find*.

The reason is doctrine are automaticly using select to access many to one relation. By using join you dont give the choice to doctrine. Example :

```
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('u, p')
        ->from($this->_entityName, 'u')
        ->leftJoin('u.profile', 'p');
```

Comment: Thx, I know it, but want to know why it's marked by yellow color